# setText fails with NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

**EDIT: Sorry guys, I figured it out. data was in fact, NULL. Silly error, should've debugged properly before posting. Apologies.**

I know this question has been asked a lot before, but I still haven't been able to solve my problem.

activity_abcd.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ActivityAbcd">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="nothing set"
            android:id="@+id/outputtv" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activityAbcd.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
public class ActivityAbcd extends Activity {




    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //STUFF
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abcd);
        new SocketTask().execute();
    }


    public final class SocketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public byte[] data;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //STUFF involving data
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputtv);
            text.setText("" + new String(data));
        }


    }


}
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException of the `text.setText("" + new String(data))` line.

I can't figure out why. I'm developing in Android studio, and the IDE generates no errors as such before running.

Comment: Try to create instance for textview inside oncreate and then use that inside asynctask

Comment: could you debug and find out if data is empty or what ?

Comment: are you sure data is not null?

Comment: Try printing the value of `data` in `Log`

Answer (score 3):

`public byte[] data;` after declaration you haven't initialized it. `data` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following.

```
byte[] data = null;
String s = new String(data);
text.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I figured it out. `data` was in fact, NULL. Silly error, should've debugged properly before posting. Apologies.